# Is it bad practice to store applications in the users home directory?

Tags: server, permissions, python, security, users

I use Ubuntu on all my servers. Recently I've started developing applications and bots that run periodically. I'm currently working on a Reddit bot in Python that is a fairly large application and consists of web scrapers, and other tools to ensure it does it's job.

They either run on cronjobs, or as independent services using systemd.

When using these applications on a server generally I will provision a server, create an unprivileged user, and store the application in the users home directory (I use Ansible for provisioning). But, I've been told by a few people this isn't a good idea - yet they failed to suggest an alternative.

Is it a bad idea to store applications in the home directory and if so where is a better place to store them?

Comment: I'm just starting out myself but I put user based apps in `/home/Me/bin/` and cron or root called apps in `/usr/local/bin/`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a bad idea to store applications in the home directory and if so where is a better place to store them?

It depends on the use-case and even then you can argue on it. Generally I would be in the "yes, bad idea"-camp.

> They either run on cronjobs, or as independent services using systemd.

This is screaming [/opt/](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html) to me. That is the directory intended for this.

The idea of `/opt`/ is to provide a tarball with all the permissions set as they should be (probably "root") and then have a service with a dedicated user/group for this service. The user unpacks the tarball, and you could direct them to a installer that would ask for user/group to use for the service.

From the link

> This directory is reserved for all the software and add-on packages that are not part of the default installation. To comply with the FSSTND, all third party applications should be installed in this directory. Any package to be installed here must locate its static files (ie. extra fonts, clipart, database files) must locate its static files in a separate /opt/'package' or /opt/'provider' directory tree.